# google cloud function price calculation issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

i want to calculate the price of a google cloud function but i am a little confused with the pricing metric networking. as they say here https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#networking

> The amount of data transferred out of your function each time it is
>   invoked.

is calculated as networking. lets say i deploy my cloud function on google cloud and some one calling that cloud function from an application that has hosted on their own servers. and my cloud function send the result of 20kb. is this also counted as networking. will google cost me for this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's correct you're charged for any outbound traffic that moves outside of Google's Network.

Depending on your usage you may sit underneath the free tier range for network traffic. Quoting from the Networking pricing page.

> Cloud Functions provides a perpetual free tier for compute-time
>   resources, which includes an allocation of both GB-seconds and
>   GHz-seconds. In addition to the 2 million invocations, **the free tier
>   provides** 400,000 GB-seconds, 200,000 GHz-seconds of compute time and
>   **5GB of Internet egress traffic per month**. Note that even for free tier
>   usage, we require a valid billing account.

Comment: thank you.. do you now any way of how to calculate the outbound traffic of a goolge cloud function

Answer (score 2):

You can export billing data to BigQuery[[1]](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery) then obtain Network Egress for Cloud Functions by running this query:

> SELECT usage_amount, usage_unit
>
> FROM billing_data_table
>
> WHERE sku.id='B068-6B82-C017' OR sku.id=’4BAF-1AD8-483C’

Cloud Functions Network Egress ‘sku.id’s are 4BAF-1AD8-483C for global, and B068-6B82-C017 for us-central-1[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/skus/?currency=EUR&filter=cloud%20function).